# Postgresql, поменять слова в строке в обратном порядке

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: Пример строки]

Нужно для каждой строки поменять слова, чтоб было в обратном порядке:
Крут Героїв бульвар,
Приміська 1-а вулиця,
и т д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Превращаем строку в массив слов, разбиваем на отдельные элементы массива, нумеруемые в обратном порядке и собираем это обратно в массив и потом в строку.

```
select array_to_string(array_agg(arr[i] order by i desc),' ')
  from (
   select str_streetname, regexp_split_to_array(str_streetname,' +') arr
     from Q
  ) A
  inner join lateral (select i from generate_series(array_length(A.arr,1),1,-1) as s(i)) X on 1=1
group by str_streetname
```

Comment: Напиши плиз еще с апдейтом строки в базе

Comment: Кроме того меняет только два слова, а на 3 уже не работает: меняет два последних

Comment: @Sanyo4ever  Странно, у меня на строку 'abc def xyz' дало 'xyz def abc'.

Comment: "Крут Героїв бульвар"
"Приміська 1-а вулиця"
"2-а Приміська вулиця"
"28 Червня вулиця"
"Березня 29 вулиця"
"Авангардна вулиця"
"вулиця Авіаційна"

Comment: Почемуто не на все строки сработало

Comment: @Sanyo4ever Обновил ответ (добавил `order by` в сборку массива), проверьте на своих данных сначала эту выборку, что бы быть уверенным в правильном порядке. Если все ok, то update вот http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d023a/2

Comment: Да всё работает, спасибо Вам большое. То что нужно